# Is it possible to get List Interface for SortedMap.values()?

Tags: java, sortedmap

SortedMap.values() returns collection with iterator, which returns values in ascending order.
I need a fast get method(by index) to this collection. My collection is unmodifiable.

My idea: Create class, which implements List Interface, and it keeps reference to collection and list to iterate.
And when we recieve get(int i):

1) if (i <= maxI) then we return value from list.

2) if (i > maxI) then we iterate to the i by collection, and copy elements to the list values.(copy only references).
And we will have O(1) amortizated.

Are there any existing implementation, or solution for this problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing all this ? Accessing elements of a Map.values() using index is itself not serving any purpose. You do not have any information about what lies at i th index. And if you really just want Random access to the elements - then simple copy the values into a List directly.

Comment: @Bhaskar It's true, though they said it's a SortedMap so maybe they do have information about that.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional way is:

```
new ArrayList<YourType>(theSortedMap.values());
```

Or `LinkedList` or whatever. All of the `Collection` implementing classes (so subtypes of `Set`, `List`, etc) have a constructor that takes a `Collection<? extends E>`. This is generally referred to as a "*conversion constructor*".

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is nearly the same for both if you expect that you need to access almost every value from the map. I would not care and simply use Arrays.asList(map.values())

Answer (score 0):

If your map is unmodifiable, and you can use third-party libraries like [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), then you could use an `ImmutableSortedMap` and then call

```
myImmutableSortedMap.values().asList()
```

which returns a random-access view in constant time.  That's probably much simpler than trying to roll your own wrapper.